# Get if TFS build agent is busy or not

Tags: rest, api, tfs

I would like to solve with TFS 2015 REST API to get if an agent is busy or not.
I tried to get requests from an agent but seems, it's listed only completed ones:

http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/_apis/distributedtask/pools/2/jobrequests?agentId=41

I looked up all possible api call but I couldn't figured out, how can I get if and agent has running build or not.

May somebody can help me out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the **latest Request** (top first request) of the response, if there is the item `"result"` (eg: `"result": "succeeded"`) in the value, then the agent is idle, otherwise it's busy.

In short :

- Idle:

  `"result": "succeeded",` or `"result": "abandoned",` or `"result": "succeededWithIssues",`
- Busy:

  **No** "result" item

You can use below PowerShell script to identify that, if the **Result** is empty, then the agent is **busy**:

```
$serverurl = "http://tfsserver:8080/tfs"
$poolid = "39"
$agentid = "147"
$baseUrl = "$serverurl/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$poolid/jobrequests?agentId=$agentid"            
$response = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential).value

$requests = @()

foreach($request in $response){

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "RequestId" = $request.requestId
          "Result" = $request.result
          "AgentName" = $request.reservedAgent.name
          "AgentVersion" = $request.reservedAgent.version
          "AgentStatus" = $request.reservedAgent.status
          "BuildDefinitionID" = $request.definition.id
          "BuildDefinitionName" = $request.definition.name
          "BuildID" = $request.owner.id
          "BuildName" = $request.owner.name
        } 

    $requests += $customObject      
}

$requests | Select-Object -first 1 `
                RequestId,
                Result, 
                AgentName,
                AgentVersion, 
                AgentStatus,
                BuildDefinitionID,
                BuildDefinitionName,
                BuildID,
                BuildName
```

Actually, the simplest way is checking the agnet status via web portal:

**Manage Project** (gear icon) --> **Agent Pools** --> Select the specific Agent pool and Agent --> Check the **Requests**

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!